# Jenkins build failed at git clone with error code 13

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I am trying my 1st Jenkins build but it failed at git clone, error code #13

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/git" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Superlist"): error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Does whatever user trying to perform the checkout have permission to execute that file?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old thread, but I had this issue because I had a space in my jenkins project name.  Create a new project without spaces and give it another go.